# How do I send java string array to sencha touch list?

Tags: json, servlets, sencha-touch-2

How do I send java string array to sencha touch list. I am using a servlet and gson and I get the error at the line JsonObject creation.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException  {
       response.setContentType("text/html");
       String[] anArray;
       anArray = new String[11]; //assign each element of array later
       JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      for(int i = 0; i <11; i++){
       myObj.addProperty(anArray[i], i);
      }
  out.println(myObj.toString());
  out.close();
```

}

eg:-
The following link uses jdbc to serve it via a database.
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/05/sencha-touch-list-example.html

Similar to this but the data is to be taken from the array of strings.

Comment: er, I don't understand what you are asking here. You want to serve json data from a servlet? But that example already demonstrates this approach, doesn't it?

Comment: Edited the question. Also even if I write out.println(anArray[1]); it doesnt load. But if I copy and paste the data outputted in browser into the data of ST-2 store, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your content type to `application/json` on line 4 -

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

and make sure you are sending properly formatted JSON from your servlet.

Comment: when I used text/html, I could not get a proper formatting. Is that what is solved, when I changed it to application/json?

Comment: @RakeshReddy: Yes, exactly. The correct MIME type for sending JSON data is `application/json`.